# In what context does "definition" arise?

Tags: proof-techniques

If I am correct, the concept of a "theorem" doesn't appear until the concept of a formal system is introduced. "Definition" is used more often than "theorem" is. So I wonder if the concept of "definition" also arise in a formal system, or some other "system" or "structure"?

Is the definition of something just a name for that thing?

Does "what a definition of something defines that thing to be" belong to the metalanguage?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There are two notions of definition: definition in the meta-language and definition in the language. When developing logic and formal systems as a mathematical field, we use definitions in the meta-language. For example, we could define various notions relating to first-order logic. These are ordinary definitions just as in any other mathematical area.

Definitions in the language, in contrast, are abbreviations. For example, suppose that we are studying propositional logic, and our original language includes only the connectives $\lnot$ and $\lor$. We can define $\land$ by
$$ A \land B = \lnot (\lnot A \lor \lnot B). $$
This is just an abbreviation. Whenever we use $\land$, we actually mean the expression above. More complicated examples are definitions of functions: a function $f(x)$ is defined as the unique $y$ such that some relation $R(x,y)$ holds. When defining functions, we also prove that $y$ always exists and is always unique. It is still an abbreviation, though.

There are two corresponding notions of theorems. Theorems in the metalanguage are results proved as in any other mathematical field. Theorems in the language are results provable from the axioms of the formal system using the derivation rules of the system. The two notions are very similar, however, in contrast to the situation with definitions.